# LCD Screen is very washed out and can only be viewed from very wide angles

Tags: lcd

I have a Fluke Cable Analyzer DTX-1800, which is a Network Cable tester. The screen is all washed out and is really hard to read when I look at it. I have to view it, looking at it, from almost a 10 degree angle to read the screen.

The unit is kind of expensive to replace and I often dabble in electronics as a hobby, I decided to open it up and see if I might be able to figure out the problem. I took the unit apart and found it to be kind of dirty and their is some corrosion of some of the circuits, specifically in areas where it is exposed to the elements (like the ports and the area where the Li-ion battery plugs in). I did a little clean-up on the corrosion.

The LCD screen is a HANTRONIX, INC Model HDM3224CL-S-T.... When I first turn on the screen, for about a split second, the color appears normal on the screen and then immediately becomes washed out in brightness and can only be read from a steep angle.

So what I am thinking is, the problem might not be the screen but something else, as it does display normally for a split second. Anyone have any opinions or suggestions on this?

I am guessing my next step will be to get the specs for the screen and maybe try to connect it to something else to see if it displays normally.

Comment: Please post the contacts question as a new question. I was going to suggest that the corrosion may have affected the contrast setting potential but ypu found a "stronger" influence :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it was the contrast on the screen, somehow it got turned way down. I just wasn't expecting it because of the way the person who brought it to me described the way it happened. Really, there is no excuse though... I should have checked the contrast first.

Comment: Just adding that in order to change contrast you have to push and hold the brightness key.